# How to set file owner to Logged in user?

Tags: abap, sap-basis

When creating a file using OPEN DATASET, SAP creates the File with the owner as `<sysID>adm`.

How to set this as the logged in user?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you would need to create an External OS Command in SM69 for CHOWN (or similar) and then execute that (use FM SXPG_COMMAND_EXECUTE) after you've finished creating the dataset.

Comment: Sorry, it's been a while since I did any real UNIX.  I think the point remains, there isn't an option to specify who owns the file in ABAP - it needs to be done at the OS level.

Answer (score 1):

You can NOT set SAP user as owner of some file. SAP user is not a user in UNIX. More exact answer can be given if you would specify your requirements.